# @include outer-container not taking default defined in grid-settings

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

So I've got my `_grid-settings.css.scss` defined as per the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#using-neat) and in it, among some of the other default overrides is `$max-width: 1200px;`.

Part of the contents of my override:

```
$visual-grid: true;
$visual-grid-color: green;
$visual-grid-index: front;
$visual-grid-opacity: 0.2;

$column: 90px;
$gutter: 30px;
$grid-columns: 8;
$max-width: 1200px;
```

I know this is working because I'm using the visual grid as well and when I change `$max-width` to `100%` I see that change occur.

The problem I'm having is that my `@include outer-container` on my `body` is not being respectful of this value, contrary to the [docs](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#outer-container), it seems not to notice it.

```
body {
  @include outer-container;
}
```

When I change this to `@include outer-container(1200px);` the content then falls into place alongside the rest of the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was also using Bitters and did not know that it has its own grid settings as well. I had to make sure that I uncomment `@import "grid-settings";` from `base/_base.css.scss` as per the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters#installation)' instructions.